# mySQL in need of a more efficient way to check for and add values to database

Tags: php, mysql

I have two variables,

UserID, and User_Links,

As example,

```
UserID = 10098729
User_Links = 10432,78723,78263,21829,759273,108797,21167 (this is a string)
```

The table I am considering is set up as follows:

Table Name: User_Links

```
Link_ID  User_1    User_2
1        89982100  10098729
2        10098729  12482109
3        13210012  27919828
4        17781722  10098729
```

Essentially, this table links the User to other Users by ID.

My variable UserID is the user, and the User_Links string are the users that I want to link the current user to (UserID).

However, I only want to add these values (adding the UserID in the User_1 column and the User_Links values to User_2) to my database IF the link is not already there.

I am just looking for advice, and possibly the best way to write this query.

So far, I have considered creating (from the string) and iterating through the array of User_Links and checking if each value exists in the database, and then running a query to add it if it does not. (this seems so inefficient)

I have also considered using an IN statement, but I am not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 4):

- Add a unique constraint to (User_1, User_2)
- If your links are symmetric (meaning that "foo"->"bar" is the same as "bar"->"foo") always insert the rows such that User1 < User2.

Then just insert rows, ignoring errors due to duplicate keys.

Comment: And combine with `INSERT IGNORE`.

Comment: +1 to your comment on `INSERT IGNORE`. No need to check if the values already exist.

Comment: @Konerak: After reading this of course: [“INSERT IGNORE” vs “INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)